# How to build a push-notifications service with Spring and Websocket

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, websocket

##### What we have on start

Let's say there is a simple Spring Boot application which provides an API for some frontend. Tech stack is quite regular: `Kotlin`, `Gradle`, `Spring WebMVC`, `PostgreSQL`, `Keycloak`.
The frontend interacts with the app synchronously via HTTP. Client authenticates with JWT token.

##### The business task

There is a list of events that could be raised somewhere in the system. User should be notified about them.

User is able to subscribe to one or more event notification. Subscriptions is just a pair of `user_id + event_type_id` persisted in dedicated Postgres table.

When event X is being raised we should find all the users subscribed to it and send them some data via `Websocket`

Comment: More robust solution will be to use AMQP with spring, as messages can be lost with web-sockets

Answer (score 1):

##### Configuration

Let's configure Spring first. Spring uses a STOMP over Websocket protocol.

Add dependencies to `build.gradle.kts`

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
implementation("org.springframework:spring-messaging")
```

Add a Websocket config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebsocketConfig(
    private val websocketAuthInterceptor: WebsocketAuthInterceptor
) : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/")
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*")
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
    }

    override fun configureClientInboundChannel(registration: ChannelRegistration) {
        registration.interceptors(websocketAuthInterceptor) // we'll talk later about this
    }
}
```

`registerStompEndpoints` is about how to establish connection with our websocket. The config allows frontend interact with us via `SockJS` of `Websocket` libraries. What they are and what the difference is not a today's topic

`configureMessageBroker` is about how we will interact with the frontend after the connection established.

`configureClientInboundChannel` is about message interception. Let talk about it later.

Add `/ws/**` path to ignored patterns in the Spring Security config.

##### Connection establishing

On the frontend side it should looks something like that (JavaScript)

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://<api.host>/ws')
//const socket = new SockJS('http://<api.host>/ws') // alternative way
const headers = {Authorization: 'JWT token here'};
 
const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket, {headers});
stompClient.connect(
    headers,
    function (frame) {
        stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification', 
        function (message) { ...message processing... });
    });
```

The key moment is to pass an authorization header. It is not a HTTP header. And initial HTTP handshake itself will not be authorized. This is the reason of adding `/ws/**` to ignored patterns.
We need the header and the token because we want to allow websocket connection only for authorized users and also we want to know which exactly user is connected.

##### Authentication

Now we are adding the authentication mechanism

```
@Component
class WebsocketAuthInterceptor(
    private val authService: AuthService, //your implementation
    private val sessionStore: WebsocketUserSessionStore
) : ChannelInterceptor {

    override fun preSend(message: Message<*>, channel: MessageChannel): Message<*>? {
        val accessor: StompHeaderAccessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor::class.java)
        val sessionId: String = accessor.messageHeaders["simpSessionId"].toString()

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.command) {
            val jwtToken: String = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization")
            val token: AccessToken = authService.verifyToken(jwtToken)
            val userId: Long = token.otherClaims["user_id"].toString().toLong()
            sessionStore.add(sessionId, userId)
        } else if (StompCommand.DISCONNECT == accessor.command) {
            sessionStore.remove(sessionId)
        }
        return message
    }
}
```

The point is to link a random generating websocket session ID with a user ID from our Spring Security store and persist that pair during the session life. JWT token should be parsed from the message headers.

Then by the given token a user ID should be obtained. Implementation of that part depends on what Spring Security config you exactly have. In case of Keycloack there is a useful static method `org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier::verifyToken`

`WebsocketUserSessionStore` is just a map for linking `session_id` with `user_id` It may looks like the following code. Remember the concurrent access of course

```
@Component
class WebsocketUserSessionStore {
    private val lock = ReentrantLock()
    private val store = HashMap<String, Long>()

    fun add(sessionId: String, userId: Long) = lock.withLock {
        store.compute(sessionId) { _, _ -> userId }
    }

    fun remove(sessionId: String) = lock.withLock {
        store.remove(sessionId)
    }

    fun remove(userId: Long) = lock.withLock {
        store.values.remove(userId)
    }
}
```

##### Notification actually

So event A was raised somewhere inside business logic. Let's implement a websocket publisher.

```
@Component
class WebsocketPublisher(
    private val messagingTemplate: SimpMessagingTemplate,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    private val sessionStore: WebsocketUserSessionStore,
    private val userNotificationRepository: UserNotificationRepository
) {
    suspend fun publish(eventType: EventType, eventData: Any) {
        val userIds = userNotificationRepository.getUserSubscribedTo(eventType)
        val sessionIds = sessionStore.getSessionIds(userIds)

        sessionIds.forEach {
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                it,
                "/queue/notification",
                objectMapper.writeValueAsString(eventData),
                it.toMessageHeaders()
            )
        }
    }

    private fun String.toMessageHeaders(): MessageHeaders {
        val headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE)
        headerAccessor.sessionId = this
        headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true)
        return headerAccessor.messageHeaders
    }
}
```

`EventType` is an enumeration of event types the system has.

`UserNotificationRepository` is just a part of data persistence layer (Hibernate|JOOQ repository, MyBatis mapper or smth). Function `getUserSubscribedTo` should do something like `select user_id from user_subscription where event_type_id = X`.

The rest of code is plenty straightforward. By the giving userIds it is possible to obtain living websocket sessions. Then for every session `convertAndSendToUser` function should be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think they have [the tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-scheduled-websocket) to build the WebSocket push-notification service.